# Deducing a likelihood from a prob. mass function.

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

How does one derive the likelihood from the pmf below?

[image]

I think I can derive the first 2 branches of the likelihood. For example the pmf has $x=\theta/2, \ x=2\theta, \ x=2\theta+1$ for theta even. The first equation is valid whether x is even or odd. The second only valid for x even, and the third when x is odd. We do a similar reasoning for the second branch. So, re-equate the equations in terms of x, and get the first two branches of the likelihood. I have no idea how to obtain the third one...

There's no need for a context, all you need is right there. But if you'd like to know more the example was taken from [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.lnms/1215466216), page 7 (127), section 5.3.2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any thoughts of your own?

Comment: @Math1000 I've edited the question. Thanks

Comment: @Math1000 any thoughts on this ? ;)

Comment: The likelihood is obviously $\frac13$ on some set $S$ of $(x,\theta)$ points and the question is to describe the set of $\theta$s such that $(x,\theta)$ is in $S$ for each $x$, while $S$ is given as a set of $x$s such that $(x,\theta)$ is in $S$ for each $\theta$. To perform this inversion, which has nothing to do with probability, note that $S$ is the set of points $$(\theta/2,\theta)\ (\theta\ \text{even})\quad((\theta-1)/2,\theta)\ (\theta\ \text{odd})\quad(2\theta,\theta))\ (\text{no condition})\quad(2\theta+1,\theta))\ (\text{no condition})$$ and ...

Comment: ... $$(1,1)\quad(2,1)\quad(3,1)$$ or, equivalently, $$(x,2x)\ (\text{no condition})\quad(x,2x+1)\ (\text{no condition})\quad(x,x/2)\ (x\ \text{even})\quad(x,(x-1)/2)\ (x\ \text{odd})$$ and $$(1,1)\quad(2,1)\quad(3,1)$$ and you are (almost) done. Any mystery remaining?

Comment: @Did Thanks for your help. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to help resolving this issue.  Let's put aside for the moment the case $\theta=1$.

I suggest looking at the values of $\theta$ columnwise.  The first column is $x=\theta/2$ when $\theta$ is even and $(\theta-1)/2$ when $\theta$ is odd.

We notice that these give the same image $x$ for two consecutive numbers $\theta$, even-odd . In other words  if $\theta=2k$ and $\theta=2k+1$, for  $k=1,2,3\ldots$,  then $x=k$.

Another important think is that there are no "gaps" in the values of $x$. This means that $x$ takes all possible values  $2,3\ldots$. So, for  any value  of $x\neq 1$ either odd or even there correspond  two values of $\theta$,   $\theta=2x$ and $\theta=2x+1$.

For the other two  branches  one  can express  $x$ by merging the two  expressions as $x=2\theta$ and $x=2\theta+1$, $\theta=2,3,\ldots$.
These two functions are depicted on the whole range of values, the former  on  the evens and   the second on the odds. So for $x$ even $\theta=x/2$ and for $x$ odd $\theta=(x-1)/2$.

Now, when $x=1$, $\theta=1$(obvious),  $\theta=2$,  from top equation, and $\theta=3$ from middle equation.

Q: $P(\delta(X)=\theta)$=?

A: Assume that $\theta=1$. Observing the pmf   we see that the only possible values for $X=1,2,3$  each with probability 1/3 and $\delta(1)=\delta(2)=\delta(3)=1$.

Therefore $P(\delta(X)  = 1) =P(1,2,3)=1$.

Now assume that $\theta\neq 1$.  The probability  can break as $$P(\delta(X)  = \theta) =P(X \;\text{is even};\delta(X)  = \theta) +P(X \;\text{is odd};\delta(X)  = \theta) $$ $$=P(X \;\text{is even};X  = 2 \theta) +P(X \;\text{is odd};X  = 2\theta+1) $$ $$=P(X  = 2 \theta) +P(X  = 2\theta+1) $$

The last equality holds because $2\theta$ is  even and  $2\theta +1$ is odd for every $\theta$ and $X$ is even or $X$ is odd are larger events than $X=2\theta$ and $X=2\theta+1$, respectively.

Finally,  $$P(X  = 2 \theta) +P(X  = 2\theta+1)=1/3+1/3=2/3 $$

Comment: Not sure I follow you on everything, but your last line was helpful. By the way how would you compute $P(\delta(X)=\theta)$, where $\delta(x)$ would be $x/2$ for even, $(x-1)/2$ for odd $\neq 1$, and $1$ otherwise?

Comment: All probabilities are 1/3. The x's change according to $\theta$, For example  when $\theta=1$ P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(X=3)=1/3. Let's say $\theta=3$, odd. Then, P(X=1)=P(X=6)=P(X=7)=1/3. Or, if $\theta=10$, even. Then, P(X=5)=P(X=20)=P(X=21)=1/3.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you there... Since $P_{\theta}(\delta(X)=\theta)=P(\delta(X)=\theta|\theta)$. For the branch $\delta(X)=1$, $P(\delta(X)=\theta|\theta)=P(1=\theta|\theta)$, which is equal to 1 when $\theta=1$ and zero otherwise... I think. In page 8 (eq. 5.3.2) of the reference in the question, I found something similar, yet somewhat different. :/ I was trying to obtain that.

Comment: I have included my reply in the   answer  to your original question.

Comment: theoGR I agree with you, but I think you should also add a term $P(X =1;\delta(X)=\theta)$ and correct one of the terms to $P(X\neq 1 \text{ and odd}; \delta(X)=\theta)$ which is equal to $0$ for the $\theta \neq 1$.

Many thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: You are welcome!